# What's the advantage of returning Task<Document> over Task<Solution> in a code fix that affects one file

Tags: c#, roslyn

When creating a Code Fix you can choose between returning a `Task<Document>` and a `Task<Solution>`. Obviously the latter should be chosen when you (potentially) modify multiple documents like a `Rename` action.

If only the current document is modified is there a guideline on what should be returned? It seems most logical to just return `Task<Document>` but what is done as the next step? If it continues by returning `Task<Solution>` without anything else, we might as well do that ourselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't override `GetChangedSolutionAsync`, the [base implementation](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/CodeActions/CodeAction.cs,128) will simply get the solution from `GetChangedDocumentAsync`.

The point of overriding `GetChangedDocumentAsync` is just to let you write simpler code.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example that overrides `GetChangedDocumentAsync `? I haven't seen it used in the wild yet and I'm not sure what simplicity I should expect from it.

Comment: I think the simplicity is you just don't have to return `myNewDocument.Project.Solution`.